# Sitecore: How to get Item's Alias Url

Tags: sitecore, alias, sitecore6

Is it possible to get the Alias url of an Item from .NET? I am able to use Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider class to get the item's default url, but I haven't found a way to get the Alias url.

Comment: I answered the similar question the other day: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919116/how-to-check-whether-sitecore-item-is-using-alias/6922452#6922452. See if the mentioned API contains the way to get the info you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a method built into the Sitecore API anywhere that does that, but you could try something like this ...

```
string query = String.Format("/*/system/Aliases//*[@@templateid='{0}' and contains(@Linked item, '{1}')]", Sitecore.TemplateIDs.Alias, Sitecore.Context.Item.ID);
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item alias = Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectSingleItem(query);
string aliasUrl = string.Empty;
if (alias != null) {
    aliasUrl = String.Format("/{0}.aspx", alias.Name);
}
```

(I have not tested this, it's based on some code I'm already using + some other stuff off the top of my head.)