# Sitecore GetItemUrl() resolving to alias

Tags: sitecore

I've created an alias (basically a virtual (or alternative) path in Sitecore) for an item that was also re-named. My custom redirect handler is then determining the item ID for the old link correctly.

But when I call `LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, urlOptions)` the resulting URL is for the alias, not the actual Sitecore item that exists in the content tree.

Is this Sitecore's default behavior for `LinkManager.GetItemURL()` to resolve to an item's alias, if one exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [possibly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792757/sitecore-linkmanager-getitemurl-resolving-to-alias/8868037) with a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792757/sitecore-linkmanager-getitemurl-resolving-to-alias/8868037#8868037).

1. Can you ensure you're not using a custom `LinkProvider`, e.g. the [custom LinkProvider on the shared source](http://trac.sitecore.net/LinkProvider/browser/Trunk/Links/LinkProvider.cs)? If you are using that, part of its behavior is to apply aliases for item links.
2. Another thing would be to look at your HTML output caching and ensure that's not the issue (as referenced in the above link for the other question).

Also, what version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: That's what's puzzling about this.  I'm not using a custom LinkProvider.  I'm using the one that comes with the Sitecore API.  When I step through the code, I'm able to see where it's passing the Sitecore item into the GetItemUrl(item, urlOptions) method and returning the URL for the alias.  The version that I'm running is Sitecore 6.4.1

Comment: Correction - it is using the "shared source" link provider.

Comment: That seems odd.  Why is this the the behavior of the "shared source" version?

Comment: Its just a feature of that shared source component. I didn't make it but I would assume the reasoning is that if you have an alias URL and a main full URL, you'd want to avoid duplicate URLs for search engines, so it prefers the shortened alias URL for any link of that item. Again, just a guess. If this answers your question don't forget to mark it as the answer.

Comment: Hi Mark, may i know if this has been fixed in Sitecore 6.4++?